Given $f(x,y) =\begin{cases}\frac{ x^3} { x^2 + y^2}, &(x,y)\neq (0,0) \\ 0, &(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$, is  f differentiable at $(0,0)$?
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        & D_1f(0,0) = 1, \quad D_2f(0,0) = 0. \\
        & \textbf{If \( f \) is differentiable at \( (0,0) \), the following must hold:} \\
        & \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h) - f(0) - Ah}{\|| h \||} \\
        &= \lim_{(h_x, h_y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\frac{h_x ^3}{h_x^2 + h_y^2} - h_x}{\sqrt{h_x^2 + h_y^2}} \\
        &= \lim_{(h_x, h_y)\to(0,0)} \frac{h_x ^3 - h_x (h_x^2 + h_y^2)}{\sqrt{h_x^2 + h_y^2}(h_x^2 + h_y^2)} \\
        &= \lim_{(h_x, h_y)\to(0,0)} \frac{h_x^3 - h_x^3 - h_x h_y^2}{\sqrt{h_x^2 + h_y^2}(h_x^2 + h_y^2)} \\
        &= \lim_{(h_x, h_y)\to(0,0)} \frac{- h_x h_y^2}{\sqrt{h_x^2 + h_y^2}(h_x^2 + h_y^2)}
    \end{aligned}  
\end{equation*}
I personally think it is differentiable because as $h→0$, it converges to $(0,0)$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Hint: what do you think about $\lim_{r\to0}\frac{-r^3\cos t\sin^2t}{r^3}$?

@AnneBauval Using your hint, I came to the following:
If you take lim →0 with h_x = r cos, h_y =r sin, you get cos⁡() ^ 3
That is not equal to 0, and thus the function is not differentiable.

Right. See also the linked post in the closure banner above, or that one and probably several other ones.

Assume $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.
We have the following for functions differentiable at point $c = (c_1, c_2)$:
\begin{equation}
Df(c)\left( (x,y) - c \right) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(c) (x - c_1) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(c) (y - c_2)
\end{equation}
So we can write:
\begin{equation}
Df(0,0)\left( (x,y) - (0,0) \right) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) y
\end{equation}
We are provided
\begin{equation}
D_1 f(0.0)=1, \quad D_2 f(0.0)=0
\end{equation}
Thus,
\begin{equation}
Df(0,0)((x,y)) = 1 \quad \text{for all} \ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2
\end{equation}
But, also,
If we take $(x,y) = (a,b)$ and $t \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, with $a \neq 0, b \neq 0$, we have:
\begin{equation}
Df(0,0)(a,b) = f_{(a,b)}(0,0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} \left( f((0,0) + t(a,b)) - f(0,0) \right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} \left( f(ta, tb) \right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} \frac{a^3 t^3}{t^2 a^2 + t^2 b^2} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} \frac{a^3}{a^2 + b^2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{a^3}{a^2 + b^2} =  \frac{a^3 }{a^2 + b^2} \neq 1, \quad \textrm{for some values of a and b}.
\end{equation}
This is a contradiction.
Thus, it is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Please do not duplicate answers to such a FAQ.
